# java CompletableFuture completion sequence

Tags: java, completable-future

From CompletableFuture javadocs:

> Actions supplied for dependent completions of non-async methods may be
> performed by the thread that completes the current CompletableFuture,
> or by any other caller of a completion method.

and looking into `CompletableFuture.complete()` it calls `postComplete()` which seems to pop off the dependent chains and tries to complete them.

To test my understanding, I wrote a simple program

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
public class TestCompletableFuture {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<Void>()
            .whenComplete((res, exc) -> {
                System.out.println("inside handle.");
                if (exc != null) {
                    System.out.println("exception.");
                }
                System.out.println("completed.");
            }
        );

        future.completeExceptionally(new Exception("exception"));
        System.out.println("done.");
    }
}
```

the output of the code:

```
done.
```

From my understanding, when the main thread calls `future.completeExceptionally()` it should invoke the function passed into `CompletableFuture.whenComplete()`.

Why is this not the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are completing the wrong future. You need to get a reference to the first stage and complete that to see the `whenComplete` in action:

```
public class TestCompletableFuture {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // get reference
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        
        // configure the action that to be run when the future is complete
        CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = future
                .whenComplete((res, exc) -> {
                            System.out.println("inside handle.");
                            if (exc != null) {
                                System.out.println("exception.");
                            }
                            System.out.println("completed.");
                        }
                );

        future.completeExceptionally(new Exception("exception"));
        System.out.println("done.");
    }
}
```

So, now the code speaks for itself... When the `future` is complete run that action `(res, exc) -> {...}`. And then just trigger that completion on the `future` by calling `completeExceptionally(...)` on it.

Another thing to note is that all of the above stages (futures) are completed exceptionally now:

```
System.out.println(future.isDone()); // true
System.out.println(future2.isDone()); // true

System.out.println(future.isCompletedExceptionally()); // true
System.out.println(future2.isCompletedExceptionally()); // true
```

Comment: Oh wow, I did not know that :) thanks for the catch and explanation!